# How to get a list of monomials of a polynomial without coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, expression-manipulation

Giving a polynomial, say

```
a x^2 + b x y + c y^2
```

`MonomialList[a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, {x, y}]` just gives

```
{a x^2, b x y, c y^2}
```

How can I get a list ***without*** the coefficients? I mean, the following list

```
{x^2, x y, y^2}
```

The motivation of this question is, I am only interested in the structure of the polynomial itself, i.e., **which kinds of of monomials are there, while their explicit coefficient are not relevant**.

Answer (score 9):

You can generate the monomials by using `CoefficientRules`, like this

```
In[55]:= monomialList[poly_, vars_] := Times @@ (vars^#) & /@ CoefficientRules[poly, vars][[All, 1]]
         monomialList[a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, {x, y}]

Out[56]= {x^2, x y, y^2}
```

Answer (score 7):

A pattern matching method:

```
fn[x_, {var__}] := List @@ Pick[x, x, Alternatives[var]^_.]

fn[a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {x^2, x y, y^2}
> ```

But a better approach I believe is *(hopefully now corrected at last)*:

```
fn2[x_, var_] := Collect[List @@ Expand @ x, var, 1 &]

fn2[a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {x^2, x y, y^2}
> ```

```
fn2[x (x^2 + y^2), {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {x^3, x y^2}
> ```

```
fn2[p x + a x^2 + b x y, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {x, x^2, x y}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is very clever and efficient!

Comment: @user29373 Don't miss my last update; I like it best.  And you're welcome.

Comment: Thanks again @Mr.Wizard! That is really fantastic.

Comment: Maybe add `Expand` in there? Try `fn2[x(x^2 + y^2)]` as it is now.

Comment: @Marius Thank you.  I think the simple change I just made catches that case.  Would you please test it?

Comment: this `fn2[p  x +  a x^2 + b x y, {x, y}]` doesnt work quite right ( `fn` works .. )

Comment: @george2079 I am getting too sleepy.  My "bug fix" introduced evaluation that I did not want.  I think Marius's suggestion of `Expand` is hopefully more correct.  I am going to edit *once again* to use that instead.  Please tell me if you find a situation where that one fails.

Comment: `fn2[(a + b + c) (x^2 + x y + y^2), {x, y}] (* {x^2, x^2, x^2, x*y, x*y, x*y, y^2, y^2, y^2} *)`

Answer (score 5):

This uses some *undocumented* functionality:

```
poly = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2; vars = {x, y};
dl = GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[poly, vars];
Inner[Power, vars, #, Times] & /@ dl[[1, All, 1]]
```