# Undocumented fourth parameter of Collect; how long has it been there?

Tags: functions, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, undocumented

While tinkering with [How to get a list of monomials of a polynomial without coefficients?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88762/121) on a whim I tried a fourth argument in [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html) and found:

```
Collect[(x + y + z + 1)^2, {x, y}, foo, bar]
```

> ```
> bar[bar[foo[1 + 2 z + z^2], y foo[2 + 2 z], y^2 foo[1]],
>   x bar[foo[2 + 2 z], y foo[2]], x^2 bar[foo[1]]]
> ```

It seems that in addition to a third parameter that applies to coefficients the fourth parameter takes the place of `Plus` to reassemble the expression.  I also note that this functionality has been present since at least version 7.0.1.

- Is this understanding correct?
- When was this introduced and has it changed any since then?
- Has this been discussed here before?
- What uses might this be put to?

Comment: It's been around since at least V5.2 (2006) and seems unchanged since then. That's as much as I know.

Comment: Introduced in either version 3 or 4, I forget which. Not sure if it has changed since then.

Comment: @Daniel Since this is a longstanding feature is there a reason it has not been documented?

Comment: It is not really the most carefully designed of features. (Or so claims the developer who put it in 20 or so years ago.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an answer generated from the comments.

D. Lichtblau:

> Introduced in either version 3 or 4, I forget which. Not sure if it has changed since then.

It's later than version 4.1:

[image]

Mr.Wizard:

> Since this is a longstanding feature is there a reason it has not been documented?

D. Lichtblau:

> It is not really the most carefully designed of features. (Or so claims the developer who put it in 20 or so years ago.)