# How to arrange the obtained results according to the descending power of x?

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials, formatting

The function of the code is to obtain a univariate quadratic equation about `x` by simultaneous equation

the code is this：

```
Clear["`*"]

eqns = {x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1, y == k (x - x0) + y0};  

polyex = Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}];

polys = Numerator[Together[polyex]];

xpoly = Collect[Resultant[polys[[1]], polys[[2]], y], x]
```

the result is follows：

```
-a^2 b^2 + (b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2 + a^2 k^2 x0^2 - 2 a^2 k x0 y0 + 
 a^2 y0^2 + x (-2 a^2 k^2 x0 + 2 a^2 k y0)
```

How to get the results I want:

```
(b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2+x (-2 a^2 k^2 x0 + 2 a^2 k y0)+a^2 k^2 x0^2 - 2 a^2 k x0 y0 + a^2 y0^2-a^2 b^2
```

If I want to get a further result, it is to factorize each item and how to deal with it. The further result is as follows:

```
(b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2+2a^2 k (- k x0 + y0)x+a^2 k^2 x0^2 - 2 a^2 k x0 y0 + a^2 y0^2-a^2 b^2
```

**(b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2+2a^2 k (- k x0 + y0)x+a^2 k^2 x0^2 - 2 a^2 k x0 y0 + a^2 y0^2-a^2 b^2**

The result in bold is what I finally want, and it is to combine the similar items and arrange them according to the descending power of x, and the coefficients in each similar item can be factorized. Or in the form of a whole

Thank you！

@bmf
Today I took a look at the documentation on using collect. The usage of Collect [f _ djinx _ simple] decomposes every term, but the output is sometimes arranged by the ascending power of x, sometimes by the descending power.
What's the reason for this?

Such as：

```
eqns = {x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1, y == k (x - x0) + y0};  
polyex = Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}];
polys = Numerator[Together[Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}]]];
xpoly = Collect[Resultant[polys[[1]], polys[[2]], y], x];
Collect[xpoly, x, Simplify]
```

the result is:

```
(b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2 + 2 a^2 k x (-k x0 + y0) + 
 a^2 (-b^2 + (-k x0 + y0)^2)
```

but

```
eqns = {x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1, y == k x + m}; 
polyex = Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}];
polys = Numerator[Together[Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}]]];
xpoly = Collect[Resultant[polys[[1]], polys[[2]], y], x];
Collect[xpoly, x, Simplify]
```

the result is:

```
a^2 (-b^2 + m^2) + 2 a^2 k m x + (b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is the following:

```
Collect[xpoly, x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &]
```

> [image: poly]

**Edit:** we have established that

```
res = (b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2 + 
   x (-2 a^2 k^2 x0 + 2 a^2 k y0) + (-a^2 b^2 + a^2 k^2 x0^2 - 
     2 a^2 k x0 y0 + a^2 y0^2);
```

Then, we can

```
Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[res, x], x]
```

> [image: res]

However, after the edit in the OP it seems that the desired thing is to manipulate each term separately. I suggest

```
CoefficientList[xpoly, x] // Factor // FullSimplify
```

> [image: coeflist]

**Edit 2:** it is obvious that the following

```
Collect[Coefficient[res, 
    x^2] x^2 + (Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[res, x], x]) x + 
  Select[res, FreeQ[x]], x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &]
```

gives

> [image: final]

**Edit 3:** using only the code from the O.P -which means `xpoly`- and a one-liner

```
Collect[Coefficient[xpoly, x^2] x^2 +
  Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[xpoly, x], x] x + 
  Select[xpoly, FreeQ[x]], x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &]
```

> [image: 2]

Comment: excellent! thank you! If I want to get a further result, it is to factorize each item and how to deal with it. The further result is as follows:        (b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2+2a^2k (- k x0 + y0)x+a^2 k^2 x0^2 - 2 a^2 k x0 y0 + a^2 y0^2-a^2 b^2

Comment: @csn899 please see the edit.

Comment: thank you! I want the complete equation form, not the coefficient of a single term. That is to say, the equations are arranged according to the descending power of x after merging the similar terms. What is better is that the coefficients in front of each term of the equation can be factorized. Overall maintenance of equation

Comment: Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[res, x], x]    the result is:-2 a^2 k (k x0 - y0)

Comment: CoefficientList[xpoly, x] // Factor // FullSimplify    the result is:{-a^2 (b + k x0 - y0) (b - k x0 + y0), 2 a^2 k (-k x0 + y0), 
 b^2 + a^2 k^2}

Comment: I want the complete equation form, not the coefficient of a single term.(b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2+2a^2 k (- k x0 + y0)x+a^2 k^2 x0^2 - 2 a^2 k x0 y0 + a^2 y0^2-a^2 b^2

Comment: (b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2+2a^2 k (- k x0 + y0)x+a^2 k^2 x0^2 - 2 a^2 k x0 y0 + a^2 y0^2-a^2 b^2

Comment: @csn899 Firstly, I do not understand the reason behind leaving so many incomplete comments. Furthermore, I showed you how to arrange the powers of `x` in the order you wanted. I, also, provided an answer on how to manipulate. You can reconstruct your polynomial after manipulations. `Collect[Coefficient[res, 
    x^2] x^2 + (Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[res, x], x]) x + 
  Select[res, FreeQ[x]], x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &]`

Comment: @csn899 and again, from the way you wrote the comments, it's not clear to me what you are asking/trying to achieve. Can you please, have a look at the second edit and if you are not happy explain me what more you need in one comment so we can make progress?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Collect[Coefficient[res, 
    x^2] x^2 + (Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[res, x], x]) x + 
  Select[res, FreeQ[x]], x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &]   running this code the result is  Defer[]

Comment: @csn899 you should grab the definition of `res` for the answer `res = (b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2 + 
   x (-2 a^2 k^2 x0 + 2 a^2 k y0) + (-a^2 b^2 + a^2 k^2 x0^2 - 
     2 a^2 k x0 y0 + a^2 y0^2);`

Comment: @csn899 have a look at the [**`screenshot`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BS4U.png)

Comment: res = Collect[xpoly, x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &]
Collect[Coefficient[res, 
    x^2] x^2 + (Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[res, x], x]) x + 
  Select[res, FreeQ[x]], x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &]    Why can't it be written together like this?

Comment: @csn899 I just meant to show you how the commands work. Of course, you should feel free to adjust them now that you know your syntax according to the particular needs that you have. Also, please keep in mind, that you had a question, I gave an answer, then you edited, I added an edit to address the edit and so on. This is all to say, that you have the commands and the syntax at hand, and you know better than me the needs of your problem, ergo you have all you need to write it optimally, right?

Comment: @csn899 have a look at the final edit. This is what I meant. that you should be able to gather the relevant pieces of information and write a one-liner using your code. Note, that I only used `xpoly` as defined by you. This is what you meant, right?

Comment: @csn899 so, is the final edit what you needed?

Comment: It's amazing.This effect is what I want.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @csn899 ok, good. glad I was able to help :-)

Comment: I haven't understood this problem:       res = (b^2 + a^2 k^2) x^2 +     x (-2 a^2 k^2 x0 + 2 a^2 k y0) + (-a^2 b^2 + a^2 k^2 x0^2 -       2 a^2 k x0 y0 + a^2 y0^2);   Collect[Coefficient[res, x^2] x^2 + (Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[res, x], x]) x + Select[res, FreeQ[x]], x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &]    Why can't we get the right answer using these two lines of code？Why is it normal to replace this code? What is the reason? thank you!Collect[Coefficient[xpoly, x^2] x^2 +
  Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[xpoly, x], x] x + 
  Select[xpoly, FreeQ[x]], x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &]

Comment: @csn899 sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. both commands yield the same result; see [**`here`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08FV7.png). I just re-wrote the final command in a one line, using the code from the O.P to avoid intermediate definitions and for clarity.

Comment: Today I took a look at the documentation on using collect. The usage of Collect [f _ djinx _ simple] decomposes every term, but the output is sometimes arranged by the ascending power of x, sometimes by the descending power. 
What's the reason for this?

Comment: Side note: to learn more about the undocumented syntax of `Collect` used in this answer, read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88781/1871).