# How can I get a list of the monomials from a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, expression-manipulation

Suppose I have an expression like this one:

$\qquad x^2+4.4 y^2 + 5\ 10^2 x y$

How can I transform it into the following expression:

$\qquad \{x^2,\,y^2,\,x\,y \}$

Answer (score 4):

Following the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88762/how-to-get-a-list-of-monomials-of-a-polynomial-without-coefficients/88766#88766) by @wuyingddg,

```
monomialList[poly_, vars_] := Times @@ (vars^#) & /@ CoefficientRules[poly, vars][[All, 1]]

f[x_, y_] = x^2 + 4*4*y^2 + 5*10^2*x*y;

monomialList[f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

> {x^2, x y, y^2}

Comment: really thanks for your help

Comment: @Farid https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work